# Linux: How to move files with same name, diff ext. into their own folder?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have files like this 
This list is a sample of my files note the actual files are not in sucessive order.

```
file1.a
file2.a
file1.b
file2.b
...
```

and some have a .c extension but not all

How would I move these files into their own named folder.

I have tried this

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -l sh -c 'mkdir "${1%.*}" && mv "$1" "${1%.*}"' sh
```

but it doesn't work as intended i.e. Well it creates the folders but wont put the second file of same name different extension in the same folder.

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘./file1’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘./file2’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘./file3’: File exists
```

Comment: Use the or operand instead of and: I.e. `||` . Or use the command separator: `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `mkdir -p`, it won't complain (and break the `&&`) if directories exist (it will also create parent directories if those don't exist).

Answer (score 1):

```
for FILE in $(ls file[0-9].[a-z])
do
    DIRNAME=$(echo $FILE |cut -c1-5)
    [ -d $DIRNAME ] || mkdir $DIRNAME
    mv ${FILE}* $DIRNAME
done

This will give you:
$ ls file1 file2
file1:
file1.a  file1.b  file1.c

file2:
file2.a  file2.b  file2.c
```

Comment: While that may work for files like that my actual data is not sequential i.e. 
     mydata , yourdata

Comment: In that case, give a sample of files and the directories you'd like them to go into.  I'd expect that the setting of DIRNAME=  and the 'cut' parameters will be the bits you'll want to change.